# how to hide a col in small screens and display it big screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

how can i hide a column in small screen and expand it on xl screens using bootstrap

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to ask a question according to the [ask] page. We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is on-topic here by visiting the [help/on-topic]; asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

try using `class="d-none d-md-inline"`this in the col you want to hide.
the first for small screens the 'd-none' removes the element.And 'd-md-inline' brings the element on md and above sizes.